# How can my first while loop be done after going to my second loop

Tags: java

So if I input numbers that are not equal to 28,29,30,31 (for example days of the month) I want my first while loop to be done after the second loop. If you don't get my poor english try to run this code. I hope that will help. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Padilla8 {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        int nd, day;

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print ("Please input number of days: \t");
        nd = in.nextInt ();

        System.out.print ("1 - Monday\n2 - Tuesday\n3 - Wednesday\n4 - "
                + "Thursday\n5 - Friday\n6 - Saturday\n7 - Sunday\n");
        System.out.print ("Enter the corresponding number on what "
                + "day you want the month will start:\t");
        day = in.nextInt ();

        while (nd < 28 || nd > 31) {
            System.out.print ("Months are from 28 days to 31 days only.");
            System.out.print (" Please input number of days:\t");
            nd = in.nextInt ();
        }

        while (day < 1 || day > 7) {
            System.out.print ("Please read.");
            System.out.print ("1 - Monday\n2 - Tuesday\n3 - Wednesday\n4 - "
                    + "Thursday\n5 - Friday\n6 - Saturday\n7 - Sunday\n");
            System.out.print ("Enter the corresponding number on what day "
                    + "you want the month will start:\t");
            day = in.nextInt ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: i need the first loop to be done after going to the second loop. because if i inputted numbers that are not equal to 28,29,30 and 31 the loop will not repeat instead it will go to the second loop and after inputting a number to the second loop, the first loop will show again. i dont know if you will get this or if i answer your question correctly maybe you can try this code i think it will help.

Comment: @user3802127 if that is true for you then the code you are running is not the code you posted. There is nothing in the above code that would make the first loop "show again". I did run it and it seems to work as expected. I suspect you forgot to recompile your code after you made some (correct) fixes.

Comment: it is my code i know it will work as you expected that is why im asking how to make the first loop done after the second loop.

Comment: Yeah well you do nothing to make yourself more clear, so sorry that I misunderstood and still do not understand your intentions.

Comment: Can you post some expected output or logging, and what the actual output/logging is?

Answer (score 0):

please use flags in loop condition . 
while (day < 1 || day > 7 && flag) {
}

Comment: what is the purpose of flag?

Comment: some explanation to your answer might be useful to OP.